# Dynamically update uicollectionview cell height

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

I am working on a quite complicated case

I have a nested UICollectionView
The outer UICollectionView A is for vertical scrolling,
and it's the first cell, is UICollectionView B, for horizontal scrolling.

It has been implemented perfectly, but now there is one more requirement
When scrolling the first cell to the second page, there is one more banner appeared on the bottom of the first cell.
Therefore I need to update the height of cell when scrolling.

If I try to call invalid layout when scrolling, it will be very low efficient. Are there any more methods to support it?

[image: The Black container is vertical collectionview. The red one the horizontal collectionview. When scroll to the second page. One extra banner needed to be animated to show smoothly]

Comment: Nowadays that thing is handled by orthogonal scrolling in a compositional layout. What is the target iOS? Also, maybe post a picture to illustrate and some code to show your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

First after received the data from the server, each cell height will be calculated and [collectionview reload] will be called.

Then after layouting the collectionview, the size for each cell is cached according to the indexpath.

To implement the 'realtime' resizing, the gesture will call a resizing function directing through a delegate, and directly modify the size cache and call [collectionview.layout invalidlayout].

It looks smooth.

Comment: can you show working example?